# css sprites - a hover with images not loading correctly

Tags: css, hover, inline, css-sprites, sprite

I have some css sprites on my site in the header but when the page loads it often loads several of the 8 separate images just below where it's meant to be. Then I wait a few seconds or hover my mouse over them and it goes back to the correct positions.

Here's my CSS:

```
.x {
display: inline-block }
.x a {
display:block;
width:100px;
height:100px;
overflow:hidden;}
.x a:hover img {
margin-left:-100px;}
```

and then the HTML goes like this:

```
<div class='x'><a href='link' alt='y'><img src=
'image' /></a></div> &nbsp;
<div class='x'><a href='link' alt='y'><img
src='image' />
</a></div>
```

for 8 separate 100x100 squares in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to define css sprite is a bit different then how you are doing it.

Here is an example of how this can be achieved.

```
/* This is how to define a main image
.sprite { background: url("../link/to/spriteimage.png") 0px 0px; width: 32px; height: 32px; }

/* Assign an image like this way, by changing the position
.sprite.icon1 { background-position: -32px -32px; }
.sprite.icon1_hover { background-position: -64px -32px; }
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/PQ3nT/)

Comment: and what html do i input into the header.php ?

Comment: I am unclear about what you are asking. I dont know, what should be header.php, its your logic. I just told you how to define sprite images.

Comment: @brycead, Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/PQ3nT/) of what i was telling you about

Comment: Thank you, figured a solution from what you posted so it's loading a lot more efficiently.